# onfocus is not called when using the autofocus attribute on an input tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, autofocus

In the following example, I get only one alert box. I read that the focus is put before the JavaScript code is executed. Is there a way to get this to work on?

```
<input id="i" type="text" autofocus onfocus="alert(1)">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('i').addEventListener('focus', function() {
    alert(2);
}, false);
</script>
```

(I have only tested this in Safari)

Edit:
I can obviously do it this way (Prototypejs selector):

```
var autofocusElement = $$('input[autofocus]')[0];
callListener(autofocusElement);
```

But it looks ugly compared to only add an event listener.

Edit:

Do not worry over a lack of browser support for the autofocus attribute. It solved easily as I have done in I fiddle links to below. There is also the best solution to the problem as I can see. My question is if I can do it in a less ugly than having to call the listener manually.

http://jsfiddle.net/tellnes/7TMBJ/3/

It works fine in Firefox 3.6 since Firefox does not support autofocus. But in Safari, which supports autofocus, are not the event called.

Comment: wrong fiddle link?

Comment: @Rahul Looks like I've renamed my jsfiddle username since this was posted. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 5):

From the [HTML5 working draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control):

> There must not be more than one
>   element in the document with the
>   `autofocus` attribute specified.

So you're asking for undefined behavior anyway.

With only one `autofocus` element, under Firefox 3.6, neither of the handlers get called on page load. Manually giving the focus to the element calls both handlers (then proceeds into an infinite loop, due to the alert boxes giving the focus back to the element when closing).

The HTML5 draft does say that `autofocus` should perform the [focusing steps](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#focusing-steps) on page load, including raising the `focus` event, but chances are that browsers are not currently implementing that feature in a complete or consistent manner.

You might want to explicitly call your `focus` event handler during page load until the HTML5 spec is finished and browsers start aiming for complete support.

Comment: The point is that I do not get the second event. It was just my testing code that had two input elements. Have updated the code now.

Comment: @Christian, but it does work if you manually give the focus to the control after the page loads, right?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi It doesn't fire the addEventListener in IE8. Seems to work in Firefox.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I dont get det focus event from autofocus if it is attacked after the dom is parsed.

Comment: @matthewpavkov, IE doesn't support `addEventListener()`. I don't see the same behavior as you in Firefox, are you using the 4.0 beta?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi I didn't know IE didn't support `addEventListener()` but that certainly explains why `alert(2)` doesn't fire in IE. I'm seeing `alert(1)` and `alert(2)` firing in Firefox 3.6.12

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Ok...I'm wrong. It's not firing both events in Firefox. However, the original code was...I think. I could have sworn I saw `alert(1)` and `alert(2)`.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi haha...ok, I accidentally changed the code. I AM seeing both alerts in Firefox. Alert 1 fires, and then Alert 2, back-to-back. I only see `alert(1)`in IE.

Comment: @matthewpavkov, you mean on page load, and without triggering an infinite loop?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi In Firefox: When I load the page initially, nothing happens. When I click (or tab) onto/into the input, I get both alerts. I am not actually able to enter any text into the box, however. Even removing either of the alerts, I still cannot enter text into the input (it seems that the input loses focus right after the alert is triggered). I suppose in a way, this is sort of like an infinite loop, but the loop only continues so long as the user brings focus to the input, over and over. In IE, I only see the first alert. Also, I am able to enter text into the input.

Answer (score 0):

The following code from your current example:

```
<input id="i" type="text" autofocus onfocus="alert(1)">

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('i').addEventListener('focus', function() {
        alert(2);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Is going to cause an infinite loop of alerts going from `1` to `2`

[eidt]

because: (this happens only in broswers that support `autofocus` )

input gets autofocus, fires event which fires an alert, alert grabs focus, click ok, input grabs focus, focus event fires new event triggering now two different alerts (DOM fully loaded now so new event is added with another alert), both alerts grab focus, click ok, click ok, input grabs focus fires new event triggering now two different alerts, alert grabs focus, click ok, next alert grabs focus, click ok, input grabs focus, fires both events, alert grabs focus, click ok, next alert grabs focus, click ok, input grabs focus, fires both events, alert grabs focus, click ok, next alert grabs focus, click ok, input grabs focus, fires both events, alert grabs focus, click ok, next alert grabs focus, click ok, input grabs focus, fires both events, input grabs focus, fires both events, alert grabs focus, click ok, next alert grabs focus, click ok, input grabs focus, fires both events, input grabs focus, fires both events, alert grabs focus, click ok, next alert grabs focus, click ok, input grabs focus, fires both events, input grabs focus, fires both events, alert grabs focus, click ok, next alert grabs focus, click ok, input grabs focus, fires both events...

Textual description of an infinite process FTW!....? :P

[/edit]

In your previous examples with two auto-focuses applied it seems that the last one will be executed as in the example I have attached at the bottom. I also added a way of adding a focus event to each input based on a class name... Not sure if you're looking for that but though it might be of some help.

[JSFiddle Example of onfocus event](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Nv6ga/)

Comment: It doesn't cause an infinite loop of alerts. The onfocus/focus is a single event, with two sets of code that should be executing. There is no loop.

Comment: @matthewpavkov hmm... this did for me http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/vxErx/  the two sets of code is what cause the loop. I guess `loop` is an incorrect term for it...

Comment: Yeah...I suppose it is somewhat like a loop. But *infinite loop* suggests that the code executes over and over, in a loop, on its own. The user has to bring focus back to the input in order for the code to execute again.

Comment: @matthewpavkov but it **does** execute over and over, in a loop, on its own... In browsers that support the HTML5 `autofocus` like the OP has labeled no need to click the input again, `autofocus` does that for you...

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a value to autofocus.
 `<input id="i" type="text" onfocus="alert(1)" autofocus="">`

Answer (score 0):

1. Give autofoucs="autofocus" attribute after all events has been given to the input field.
2. You can also use addEventListener in .js file at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the autofocus `onfocus` event fires before `addEventListener` adds the event listener.

I replaced `autofocus` with `class="autofocus"` on my input element, and set the focus like this near my `addEventListener` call:

```
if(searchInput.classList.contains('autofocus')) {
  searchInput.focus();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to execute a piece of javascript code, `onfocus` for either `input`, you could use jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/focus/